# I am trying to open pdf file in new window and open the print dialog after opening the window

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to open pdf file in new window and open the print dialog after opening the window, but the print() method that opens the print dialog is blocked by the cross-origin, as the conslole returns me this error DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame. how could I fix this issue?

```js
  print() {
            var myWindow = window.open('https://mediasb.shiftinc.com/booking_pdfs/QALNHF.pdf', 'Booking', 'width=600,height=600');
       myWindow.print();
      myWindow.focus();
    }
```

```html
<button (click)= "print()"> Print</button>
```

Comment: https://mediasb.shiftinc.com have to allow cross origin requests from localhost:4200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this in angular :-

```
this.http.get('https://mediasb.shiftinc.com/booking_pdfs/QALNHF.pdf', {responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe((res) => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
        var myWindow = window.open(url, 'Booking', 'width=600,height=600');
       myWindow.print();
      myWindow.focus();
});
```

Comment: How I can do this on Vue3? 
```const myWin = window.open(url, "_blank")?.print();```
 this works on Edge and Chrome but not print in Firefox or Safari.